# Copy all arguments but the last and paste them in the last argument in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, arguments

How to copy all the arguments but the last and paste them in the last argument in Bash?

All the arguments are file locations and the last argument is the folder location.

say I have two directories /a and /b
/a contains x.txt y.txt z.txt and x.gz y.tar.gz and z.html

I need to have a script copy_script.sh which could be invoked as shown

./copy_script.sh /a/*.txt /b

and all txt files should be copied to /b

Comment: it is unclear for me, you might rephrase your question better, show us some example to better elucidate your question

Comment: What do you mean  'paste those in the last argument'?

Comment: say I have two directories /a and /b
/a contains x.txt y.txt z.txt and x.gz y.tar.gz and z.html

I need to have a script copy_script.sh which could be invoked as shown

./copy_script.sh /a/*.txt /b

and all txt files should be copied to /b

Comment: script is not necessary, just do **cp a/*.txt b/**

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to divide the arguments the way you want, but--as pointed out by others--unnecessary in this case.

```
$ set -- a b c d e
$ echo "${@:0:$#}"
a b c d
$ echo "${@: -1}"    # Space is necessary
e
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to if you are trying to do this since the "mv" and "cp" commands already understand that the last item is a destination:

```
mkdir joe      # create directory
touch a b      # create two files here
mv a b joe     # move both to new directory
ls joe         # check they are there
a   b          # yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a basic operation in bash and you dont need write a script to do what do you want, the **cp** command solve your problem just do:

```
cp a/*.txt b/
```

this copy all extensions .txt from directory **a** to directory **b**